# Why my nginx server only shows my index.html?

Tags: nginx

I have two nginx server, one is a proxy_pass and the other is where I host the web and other services.
The problem is that when I access my page, I can only see the index.html. If I try to go to "contact" he says he can not find the file.

My proxy_pass config file:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100$request_uri;
        }

location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100$request_uri;
        }
location /somedirectory/ {
    autoindex on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100$request_uri;
}
```

My second server config file:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

}
```

Any solution to see all the files on my website?Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same `location` block. The `try_files` statement will generate 404 if the file does not exist locally, before it attempts to fetch it upstream. Also, you have `proxy_pass` and `fastcgi_pass` in the same `location` - I am surprised that's not considered an error.